# Watir with Ruby on rails on Mac, Cannot get chrome browser to open in console, Please?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, watir

I'm trying to open an empty browser with the following,

```
 browser = Watir::Browser.new(chrome)
```

What is returned is NameError: uninitialized constant Watir from (pry)

I've added

gem 'pry-rails'
   gem 'Watir'

To the config file of my app carcass.

I've updated all things I can think of, Chrome driver, Watir Driver

When I search the filesystem to find the app and run the bundle script     get this error

Could not find gem 'Watir' in any of the gem sources listed in your              Gemfile or
    available on this machine.

```
Can anyone tell me what I need to do to get rid of the "    uninitialized constant Watir  " Error` so a simple test browser can    open??
```

I'm new to this so apologies if I'm not specific enough.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's just some basic ruby syntax. There are two errors. First, the interpreter complains the name `Watir` hasn't been introduced. Secondly, `chrome` should be `:chrome` which is a symbol.

```
require "watir-webdriver"
browser = Watir::Browser.new(:chrome)
```

Answer (score 1):

When using `gem`, the gem names are case-sensitive. It should be a lowercase "watir":

```
gem 'watir'
```